# traffic info overlay shows always on top of other polylines on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

did anyone find a way to draw polyline over google traffic info on android v2 maps?
I have found this issue
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4780

no one seems to take care of it... 
I wonder if there is some kind of work around for this problem

Thanks